# What is the "short-range outdoor model (ITU-1411) with a distance-dependent path-loss" mentioned in this paper?

Tags: wireless, model, loss

I am reading the paper [*Graph Embedding Based Wireless Link Scheduling with Few Training Samples*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02871), and trying to reproduce some of its results. This paper aims to solve the wireless link scheduling problem, by building a neural network that takes geographic data as inputs (distances between transmitter-receiver pairs). You can skip to my questions if you are already familiar with this problem.

---

**Model and Problem Formulation**

Suppose there are \$L\$ pairs of transmitters and receivers. Let \$h_{kj}\$ be the channel from transmitter \$k\$ to receiver \$j\$. Then the SINR (sum to interference-plus-noise ratio)  of the \$j\$-th pair is
$$SINR_j=\frac{x_jp_j|h_{jj}|^2}{\sum_{k\neq j}x_kp_k|h_{kj}|^2+\sigma_N^2}$$
where \$p_j\$ is the transmitting power of transmitter \$j\$, and \$x_j\$ denotes whether it is activated or not. \$\sigma_N^2\$ is the power of additive white Gaussian noise. The problem is to maximize the sum-rate
$$\sum_{k=1}^LB\log(1+SINR_k)$$
subject to \$x_j\in\{0,1\}\$, where \$B\$ is the bandwidth.

---

**My Questions**

The authors propose a neural network architecture to solve this problem, based only on the geographic data, i.e. distances between the transmitters and receivers, and uses no CSI (channel state information) as input. However, to train the network, I have to generate training samples, which can be computed via a classical algorithm for this problem (e.g. FPLinQ), which requires CSI.

This is where I run into trouble: How should I generate the training samples? The paper says to generate the geographic points uniformly randomly, which means no CSI is generated during this stage. However, to use FPLinQ, I must have CSI to begin with. So I deduce that there must be some way to calculate the CSI using geographic data, transmitting power, and some other information.

In particular, if I am understanding this correctly, then I need a formula to estimate \$|h_{kj}|\$ at distance \$d\$ from a transmitter, when other parameters like the transmitting power, carrier frequency, bandwidth, antenna height, etc. are given. There is only one mention of this matter in the paper, and I quote as follows:

> We use the short-range outdoor model ITU-1411 with a distance-dependent path-loss as the channel model.

There was also a reference to this recommendation (no longer available):

> *Recommendation ITU-R P.1411-8*. International Telecommunication Union, 2015.

1. Is there such an estimation for \$|h_{kj}|\$ in ITU-1411? If not, is there other reasonable way to find \$|h_{kj}|\$? Note that you may consider the following information as given:

   - location coordinates of each transmitter and each receiver.
   - transmitting power
   - noise spectral density
   - bandwidth
   - carrier frequency
   - antenna height

As I am not a professional in this field, I'd appreciate it if you could explain to me (briefly) some other concepts:

2. What does \$h_{kj}\$ mean, physically? What is its unit?
3. Is \$\sigma_N^2\$ precisely the noise spectral density? Should I change the unit of \$\sigma_N^2\$ and \$p_j\$ to Watts-per-Hertz before plugging them into the expression of SINR?

Comment: From 1 to k the transfer function or path loss is \$h_{k1}\$

Comment: @rsch - Hi, Regarding: "*There was also a reference to this recommendation (no longer avaiable): Recommendation ITU-R P.1411-8*" Just FYI, if you want a copy of that specific recommendation (I believe it was updated a couple of times after version 8), it is available via archive.org [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170101050902/http://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/p/R-REC-P.1411-8-201507-I!!PDF-E.pdf).

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you! Hopefully this will be helpful.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Are you saying that \$|h_{kj}|^2\$ is the ratio of power received by receiver \$k\$ (from transmitter \$j\$) to the transmitted power from transmitter \$j\$? How does it depend on the distance then?

Comment: Yes, basically Friis loss formula

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I took a look at the Friis formula. The one given in wikipedia is \$P_r/P_t=D_tD_r(\lambda/4\pi d)^2\$. I think I can set \$D_t=D_r=1\$ by assuming the antennas are isotropic. But I am not sure what \$\lambda\$ is. Can this \$\lambda\$ be computed if the parameters are given as in my question?

Comment: Next look at overall Link Budget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget